# have default link on active when entering the site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I will like to have my default link show as active when entering the site. can CSS do that? I already us css for my links. would Jquery be good (new to jquery)?

UPDATED:

something is not working in my code, can some one take a took at this link and tell me what i did wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/2VnXD/7/

Comment: Post your HTML. What is a default link? Can you explain what "active" is?

Comment: Apply a class `myactivelink` to the "default link" and add that class to your CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `active` css class and give your default link that class:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">test 1</a>
<a href="#" class="active">test 2</a>
<a href="#">test 3</a>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.active{
 border: 1px dashed blue;
 background-color: #eee;   
}
a{
    padding: 5px;
}
a:hover{ /*Simple Hover effect*/
 border: 1px solid red;
 color: green;    
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2VnXD/3/)**

Also, since you said you were fairly new to jQuery, here's a simple example of handling the switching between the links:

```
$("a").on("click", function(){
   $(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});​
```

Comment: lol, thank you for my css all i need is the color #ffff00 which is the active color to all my link but i need for the home page to remain active when first entering the site but disappear after clicking other links. would this be the correct way. active{
 color: #ffff00   
}
a{
    padding: 0px;
}
a:hover{ /*Simple Hover effect*/
 border: 1px solid red;
 color: green;    
}
then the Jquery would remove the class from what i am understanding?

Comment: If all you need is for the color to show up, then you honestly don't need the rest of the css. I just threw it in to make it pretty. `.active{color: #ffff00}` should be fine in your case. Now, if I'm understanding the second part correctly, you want this css class to disappear once the user clicks on any other link. If that's the case then see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2VnXD/4/  ...You'll see that `test 2` is active once you go to the page, but after you click  any of the links, the class is removed.

Comment: Anytime, glad I could help =)

Comment: it's not working, I thought i could just add it to what i got, let me specify. please review this link. http://jsfiddle.net/2VnXD/7/

Comment: Your `top` and `left` css attributes may be throwing things off. I'm not 100% sure what look you're going for, but is this any closer? http://jsfiddle.net/2VnXD/8/

Comment: I would like the home link to have the active color #ffff00 when entering the site. like www.cnbc.com and once the person clicks on another link it goes back to it's default color which is white. but also still have the attribute of when you hover over the link, the hover color is as well #ffff00. http://jsfiddle.net/2VnXD/9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2VnXD/10/ - You needed `!important` on the `.active` class to ensure it would use that property over the others for that element.

Answer (score 0):

//css

```
 .link{font-size:18px; color:black;}
 .defaultLink{font-size:24px; color:blue;}
```

//your links

```
<a class="link" href="#">link 1</a>
<a class="link" href="#">link 2</a>
<a class="link" href="#">link 3</a>
<a class="defaultLink" href="#">link 4</a>​
```